# Excel Font Size variations in List Box

Tags: excel, fonts, listbox

My code populates an Excel Form by building various labels and listbox controls into a Frame.

It positions the controls at run time depending on the data to display.

This works fine most times but sometimes a list box font appears larger, cutting off some of the text.

Various things, back colour, frame height, list height can all have an effect on the size but I cannot find a reliable pattern.
It does not help that Excel will report it is the font size set, even though it's not that size

I'm hoping some can help me cannot detect when this happens and that lead to a fix. I have tried for several years without success.

Comment: Can you provide some relevant sample code to reproduce your issue, especially how you create the objects. Normally form control objects are created with default values for all properties, so one needs to find out why in your case this doesn't work out ...

Comment: I could create a small mock up example but unsure how to get it to you.